# PHP autoloader doesn't work on remote server

Tags: php

I have a PHP autoloader function on my local and remote server.
It's important to note that file structure is the same.

PHP autoloader function:

```
spl_autoload_register("Classes_Loader");

function Classes_Loader($className) {

    $path = __DIR__.'/classes/';
    
    $ext = '.class.php';

    $full_path = $path . $className . $ext;
    
    if(file_exists($full_path)) {
        
        include_once  $full_path;
        return true;
        
    } else {
        
        return false;

    }
}
```

When I removed `file_exists()` function I got this error:

```
include_once(/home/u764455091/domains/infuzijafuzija.online/public_html/php/classes/Menu\Menu.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u764455091/domains/infuzijafuzija.online/public_html/php/autoloader.php on line 13
```

When I checked the path shown in error, `Menu.class.php` was there. There is no misspelling in namespace nor folder.
On my local server everything is working fine.
Local server is running Windows for remote server it's Linux (I don't know which one but its shared Hostinger plan).

If someone needs this here is the code of a file calling the class.

```
    include_once './php/autoloader.php';

    $menu = new Menu\Menu;

    $kategorije = $menu->retrieve_categories();

    foreach($kategorije as $kategorija) {
        $kategorija1 = str_replace('_', ' ', $kategorija);
        echo '<li><a href="?kategorija='.$kategorija.'" id="kategorija">'.$kategorija1.'</a></li>';
    }
```

Edit: I needed to use lowercase folder and file names.

Comment: @MarkusZeller yes the problem is when I create new object `$menu = new Menu\Menu;` I also tried `use Menu\Menu;`. But I don't see how to use `DIRECTOR_SEPARATOR` in my autoloader function.

Comment: How about telling more details about your file structure? When it says the file does not exist, it won't be there.

Comment: @MarkusZeller everything is in php folder except for the page that is shown to the user. In php folder is autoloader.php and categories.php also a classes folder which contains Menu folder with Menu.class.php file in it.

Comment: That does not help. Is there a structure like ...`/classes/menu/menu.class.php`?

Comment: @MarkusZeller yes `php/classes/Menu/Menu.class.php`. Class and namespace are capital (Menu).

Comment: Again, filenames and directories should be lowercase!

Comment: @MarkusZeller it worked thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backslash will break it. It looks like you need to replace it with a forward slash in the autoloader.

```
spl_autoload_register("Classes_Loader");

function Classes_Loader($className)
{
    $path = __DIR__.'/classes/';
    
    $ext = '.class.php';
    $className = str_replace('\\', '/', $className);

    $full_path = str_to_lower($path . $className . $ext);
    
    if(file_exists($full_path)) {
        include_once  $full_path;
        return true;
    } 
        
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This also helped and using the lowercase folder/filenames also i suggest to use `\\` not `\` in that code.

Comment: `classes/Menu\Menu.class.php` having that backslash in there could escape the `M`, because the backslash is an escape character which may be dangerous! Make yourself familiar with different filesystems.

Answer (score 1):

according to the [php official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php)!
spl_autoload use lowercase to load php classes
on Windows based system files are not case sensitive (Menu.class.php same as menu.class.php) but in lunix based systems Menu.class.php is file and menu.class.php is separate one

try to use lowercase for file names and keep classes capitalized

Comment: `include_once(/home/u764455091/domains/infuzijafuzija.online/public_html/php/classes/Menu/Menu.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u764455091/domains/infuzijafuzija.online/public_html/php/autoloader.php on line 13`

Comment: did you use this in your code $full_path = str_to_lower($path . $className . $ext);

Comment: No check the solution and comment on it

Comment: My solution also has the `str_to_lower()` conversion.

Comment: yes you're solution is right i suggest him to use str_to lower (i copied that from your solution)